# How to aggregate 10records at a time in collection aggregator?I want to split 100 records with collection splitter

Tags: collections, mule

How to aggregate 10records at a time in collection aggregator? I can send 10 records at a time to target. So , these 100 records should be splitted and aggregated as 10 records at one time.
My approach towards it to generate different correlationIDs for a set of records but i am not able to write MEL for that.

Comment: Please add more details on what you have attempted so far. On most questions, showing us some of your code is a good idea as well.

Comment: <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter">
            <expression-message-info-mapping messageIdExpression="#[message.id]" correlationIdExpression="#[message.correlationGroupSize &gt; 2 ? &quot;ch123&quot; : &quot;ch456&quot;]"/>
        </collection-splitter>
        <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" value="2" doc:name="Property"/>                                                                                  I tried setting the correlation id using sample data of 6 records and by making group of 2 records to send to target but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Splitter-collection will not be a optimal solution for this.Use Batch process split records and then before sending to the outbound use batch commit and give the size as 10.This will solve your problem.